# docker exec -it bash gives error "executable file not found in $PATH" - but launching bash through Kitematic works

Tags: docker

When I attempt to run `docker exec -it bash`
I get the error `executable file not found in $PATH"`

I haven't been able to find much online pertaining to this issue. I was able to launch bash through Kitematic so it wasn't a big problem but I would love to know why it wouldn't let me launch bash with exec. This is my second day with Docker so i'm sure it's something simple but I really appreciate any help. I can get.

Comment: Does the container you’re trying to run actually include `bash`?  Images based on Alpine Linux or plain BusyBox won’t necessarily.

Comment: Just to confirm - does your command include the container name? `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`

Comment: Yes it does contain the name Abbhineet, sorry, I omitted that and forgot to put a placeholder in. And David, I spoke with a senior developer and he confirmed it works on his machine with the same docker container. He hasn't seen that issue before himself

Comment: Please include the full and exact error message. What executable isn't found?

Comment: It doesn't say what executable specifically, here is the entire error: ``` starting container process caused "exec: \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH" ```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> It doesn't say what executable specifically, here is the entire error: `starting container process caused "exec: \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Actually, it does list the command, `-it` that it is looking to run. Everything after the container id is part of the command to run, and it looks like you've put the flags after the container id. You want:

```
docker exec -it $other_exec_flags $container_id $cmd_string
```

Or as Abhineet said:

```
docker exec -it <container_name> bash
```

Which is not the same as the failing command:

```
docker exec <container_name> -it bash
```